# What magic college could I have gone to before Hoard of the Dragon Queen?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms, hoard-of-the-dragon-queen

I'm joining a running campaign of HotDQ where they just finished a chapter (I don't know which, but the DM says everyone's level 4) and I'm looking for a lore-friendly magic college to be part of. I'm playing as a level 4 Tiefling Sorcerer who meets up with the party while investing and dealing with reports of "strange happenings"in the area.

What magic colleges (or universities whatever) are in the forgotten realms that my character can be a part of?

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir I am very familiar with the differences between the two. In this character's case, it's more he attended the school to learn to control his gifts and how to use them to the best of his abilities.

Comment: What is the "background" of your character?

Comment: How big of a student load did your PC take out?

Comment: Let's say 2000 gold lol. He can pay it back by doing exemplary deeds for the college, so it's why he's out and about.

Comment: @ZwiQ I took the Sage background.

Comment: @RallozarX: Excellent. Candlekeep would be a perfect fit then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are plenty of schools, colleges and even universities in the Realms. You can see a list of a fair number of them on the Forgotten Realms fandom wiki, under the [Category:Schools](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Schools). Amongst those, one of the most famous is the [Conclave of Silverymoon](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Conclave_of_Silverymoon), which comprised many colleges.

Hoard of the Dragon Queen starts in Greenest, a town on the [Uldoon Trail](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Uldoon_Trail). The closest sizeable settlements are [Berdusk](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Berdusk) and [Elturel](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Elturel). Neither is listed to have any magic schools in FR wiki, but Berdusk has a temple of Oghma, so it might be possible that your character was trained by the knowledge clerics or wizard devotees to Oghma.

If you widen the search range a bit more, you can consider a background involving the famous library of [Candlekeep](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Candlekeep) which is in the same region of Western Heartlands.

Comment: Just to help reduce risk of link rot, can you put the schools linked in "category:schools" into the answer itself?